# PHP auto answering script

Tags: php, autocomplete

I was thinking about an idea of auto generated answers, well the answer would actually be a url instead of an actual answer, but that's not the point. 
The idea is this:
On our app we've got a reporting module which basically show's page views, clicks, conversions, details about visitors like where they're from,  - pretty much a similar thing to Google Analytics, but way more simplified.
And now I was thinking instead of making users select stuff like countries, traffic sources and etc from dropdown menu's (these features would be available as well) it would be pretty cool to allow them to type in questions which would result in a link to their expected part of the report. An example:

**How many conversions I had from Japan on variant** (one page can have many variants) **3**.
would result in:

/campaign/report/filter/campaign/(current campaign id they're on)/country/Japan/variant/3/

It doesn't seem too hard to do it myself, but it's just that it would take quite a while to make it accurate enough.
I've tried google'ing but had no luck to find an existing script, so maybe you guys know anything alike to my idea that's open source and well reliable/flexible enough to suit my needs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about natural language processing - an artificial intelligence topic. This can never be perfect, and eventually boils down to the system only responding to a finite number of permutations of one question.

That said, if that is fine with you - then you simply need to identify "tokens". For example,

**how many** - evaluate to count
**conversations** - evaluate to all "conversations"
**from** - apply a filter...
**japan** - ...using japan

etc.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer, I just needed "natural language processing" bit, but your clarification on the process should help as well :)